# How to extract prices from time in R and summarize values per Minute?

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime, timestamp, calculation

I have a dataframe that is a bit difficult to handle for me:

```
Date      Time         Price   Amount
19990104  14:11:14.34  220     100
19990104  14:11:21.21  200     150
19990104  14:11:36.35  221     200
19990104  14:11:45.45  202     150
19990104  14:11:56.11  215     100
```

I try to create a complete time: `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" e.g. 1999-01-04 14:11:14` for the first row.

Afterwards I would like to find the START-Price of a minute, so the first Price in this minute, the END-Price and the highest and lowest price...
Additionaly you see the `Amount` and these values for the MINUTE, I'd like to calculate them in sum for this minute.

It is very important, that the seconds are set to zero in the result.
So the result here should be:

```
Time        Start End  Low High  Amount
1999-01-04 14:11:00  220   215  200 221   700
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Combine `Date` and `Time` column to get Timestamp. Use `floor_date` to round down the timestamp to minute level and summarise the data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  unite(Timestamp, Date, Time, sep = ' ') %>%
  mutate(Timestamp = ymd_hms(Timestamp)) %>%
  arrange(Timestamp) %>%
  group_by(Timestamp = floor_date(Timestamp, 'mins')) %>%
  summarise(Start = first(Price), 
            End = last(Price), 
            Low = min(Price), 
            High = max(Price), 
            Amount = sum(Amount))

#  Timestamp           Start   End   Low  High Amount
#  <dttm>              <int> <int> <int> <int>  <int>
#1 1999-01-04 14:11:00   220   215   200   221    700
```